# SSH from Windows STOP working abruptly to RPi 4

Tags: ssh, windows

I am not able to connect to my RPi4 via SSH (Open SSH) from windows abruptly. it was working fine and stop working suddenly. **I am able to ping to RPi from windows successfully. SSH from this windows machine to other linux machine is working fine**. **SSH to RPi4 from other devices (mobile, linux) is also working fine**. SSH from this wondows machine to RPi alone is not working abruptly.

```
ssh: connect to host 192.168.178.24 port 22: Connection timed out

Pinging 192.168.178.24 with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 192.168.178.24: bytes=32 time=2ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.178.24: bytes=32 time=8ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.178.24: bytes=32 time=3ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.178.24: bytes=32 time=2ms TTL=64

Ping statistics for 192.168.178.24:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 2ms, Maximum = 8ms, Average = 3ms
```

Do anyone had faced similar issue.?

Comment: This appears to be a Windows problem.

Comment: SSH from this windows machine to other Linux machine is working, only to RPi is not working suddenly. I tried re-installing Open SSH on windows, but didn't help.

Comment: There are lots of possibilities, IP conflicts, firewall blocking it, etc.  Start by ensuring that the IP is correct and that no other devices are using that IP.  Power off the pi and ensure the the ping fails from windows when its off.

Comment: `it was working fine and stop working suddenly` - any updates on windows or pi around the time it stopped working?